# Algorithm to detect planar decorated graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a finite, non oriented graph $\Gamma$ in which each edge is labelled by a real number.

I say that $\Gamma$ is planar if I can realize it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in a way that $d(v_i,v_j) =$ label on the edge $ij$ and edges do not cross.
Similarly I say it is spatial if I can embed it in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Q:**

- Can you exhibit an algorithm that decides if a given $\Gamma$ is planar?
- What about spatiality?
- Is such a graph even embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^n$ of a suitable $n$?

---

Motivation: A doctor wants to represent illnesses. Each vertex is a symptom, the label on the edge $ij$ is $\frac{1}{p_{ij}}$, where $p_{ij}$ is a statistical probability that symptom $i$ and symptom $j$ occur together. In this big picture, illnesses are clans of vertices in the graph, and one could use this representation to detect new syntomps of existing illnesses, or new illnesses by the nearness of some vertices.

Comment: This type of graph is more commonly called "euclidean". "planar" means it can be embedded into a plane without the edges crossing.

Comment: I like the idea, but you can hardly apply it as simple as that. Smallest $p_{ij}$ are _"too small to be measured"_, that is, they have the greatest relative error, and they correspond to the greatest $d_{ij}$ which are going to destroy everything. Think of a graph with 10 vertices, where one of the distances is 100 and all other distances are 1 - you'll never embed it in any $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/12409/106323 for the criterion that answers this question. (Or http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=355836 for the abstract of the paper, which gives the result but not the proof.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov if you answer with this comment I will accept it.

Comment: I think I should elaborate more in an answer, but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary of answers to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12394/representability-of-finite-metric-spaces).

First of all, your edge-labeled graph $\Gamma$ might not satisfy the triangle inequality. If edge $13$ has a label greater than the sum of the labels on edges $12$ and $23$, then there's no way to embed $\Gamma$ in *any* metric space; in particular, not $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$.

So we'll assume that $\Gamma$ is what is called a *finite metric space*: there are finitely many points (the vertices of $\Gamma$) and positive distances between them (the edge labels) satisfying the triangle inequality.

Even these are not guaranteed to be embeddable in $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$. One example is the $4$-vertex graph ($4$-point metric space) below:

[image: 4-point space]

Here, any $3$ points are embeddable even in $\mathbb R^1$ just fine, and are forced to lie in a straight line in any $\mathbb R^n$. But you can't put all four in $\mathbb R^n$. This is what is called a *non-flat* metric space.

The paper [Embedding metric spaces in Euclidean space](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=355836) by C.L. Morgan gives conditions for when a finite metric space is flat, and which dimensions it can be embedded into. (This just links to the abstract, which should be accessible to anybody.)

For vertices $x, y, z$ with distances $d(x,y), d(x,z), d(y,z)$ between them, define $\langle x,y,z\rangle = \frac12\left[d(x,y)^2 + d(y,z)^2 - d(x,z)^2\right]$ and let

$$\operatorname{Vol}_n(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac1{n!} \sqrt{\det \begin{bmatrix}\langle x_0, x_1, x_1\rangle & \langle x_0, x_1, x_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle x_0, x_1, x_n\rangle \\ \langle x_0, x_2, x_1\rangle & \langle x_0, x_2, x_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle x_0, x_2, x_n\rangle \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \langle x_0, x_n, x_1\rangle & \langle x_0, x_n, x_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle x_0, x_n, x_n\rangle\end{bmatrix}}$$

This is, I think, a variation of the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) which gives the $n$-dimensional volume of the polytope formed by $n+1$ points, in terms of only the distances between them. For $n=2$, this should reduce to Heron's formula for the area of a triangle.

Anyway, the conditions in the paper are that:

- If, for any $n+1$ vertices $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ of $\Gamma$, $\operatorname{Vol}_n(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n)$ isn't real (because it takes a square root of a negative number) then $\Gamma$ isn't flat, so it's not embeddable in $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$.
- Otherwise, we can embed $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb R^n$ if there is no $(n+1)$-dimensional volume (for $n+2$ vertices of the graph) which is positive.